# How to hide top bar in manjaro gnome?

Tags: gnome, manjaro

Tell me please, how to hide Top Bar and show it when the mouse hover (e.g. like Windows)?

I found only this solution https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/, but i don`t know how it install.

On extension page (https://github.com/mlutfy/hidetopbar) exist install guide, but on this step

```
gnome-extensions enable hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca
```

i got error

```
Extension “hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca” does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solver my problems: https://manjaro.ru/gnome/kak-skryt-top-bar.html#comment29220

---

1. Launch pamac (win / super => enter pamac, press enter)
2. Open the menu (3 vertical dots) => settings, find the AUR there and turn it on
3. Now look for 'hidetopbar' in pamac
4. Click on the found package and there click the Build Files tab, find the PKGBUILD code
5. We carry out the fix described here: aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnome-shell-extension-hidetopbar-git/comment-768596

That is, in this PKGBUILD we replace the line

```
package_10_locale () {
  msg2 'Installing translations ...'
  (
    cd locale
    for locale in * /
    do
      install -Dm644 -t "$ pkgdir / usr / share / locale / $ locale / LC_MESSAGES" "$ locale / LC_MESSAGES" / *. mo
    done
  )
}
```

on the

```
package_10_locale () {
  msg2 'Installing translations ...'
  (
    cd locale
    for locale in * /
    do
      install -Dm644 -t "$ pkgdir / usr / share / locale / $ locale / LC_MESSAGES" "$ locale / LC_MESSAGES" / *. po
    done
  )
}
```

6. Install the package itself
7. Find the Extensions application (where, for example, User Thems was included) and in it we find the Hide Top Bar
8. Turn on the extension, configure it as we want